# How do I troubleshoot Azure Linux App Service when logs are not including error messages

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, loopback4, azure-appservice

I have deployed an Azure Linux App Service that runs a NodeJS app with LoopBack 4 framework for quite some time now, but since last week or so, I'm having troubles deploying a new version of the application using Azure DevOps.

Last week when an app was deployed, it took several restarts for the app to be started. Since yesterday it took around 7 hours before the application was available and today (at the time of writing) it's taking 3 hours.

This is currently only in my development environment (prod will be deployed only on pull request), but I think that the same will happen to my production environment when I deploy a new version for that. Unfortunately, I can't try this at this time.

When I open the log stream, I don't see any errors beside that it `Waiting for response to warmup request for container`.

I don't know if it can have something to do with a timeout for starting the application, since I'm getting that error message in the "Diagnose & solve problems" screen, but when I run my application om my development machine, it boots in less than 5 seconds.

I tried settings the `WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT` setting to `1800` via:

- portal > app service > Configuration > Application settings
- DevOps job for settings app settings

But this doesn't have the desired result as I'm still seeing the `Waiting for response to warup request for container` message.

In the "Diagnose & Solve problems" screen in the Azure portal, I also have an error for container crash. I would expect that I would see some kind of error as for why it fails, but all I see is the following output:

```
Container qusito-core-dev_0_fdc9a431 couldn't be started: Logs = 2020-09-11T13:43:59.410899652Z   _____                               
2020-09-11T13:43:59.410934153Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2020-09-11T13:43:59.410938953Z  /  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2020-09-11T13:43:59.410942753Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2020-09-11T13:43:59.410946453Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2020-09-11T13:43:59.410950153Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2020-09-11T13:43:59.410953753Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2020-09-11T13:43:59.410957153Z 
2020-09-11T13:43:59.410960353Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2020-09-11T13:43:59.410963553Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2020-09-11T13:43:59.410966853Z NodeJS Version : v10.14.2
2020-09-11T13:43:59.410970153Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2020-09-11T13:43:59.410973453Z 
2020-09-11T13:44:00.211504840Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2020-09-11T13:44:00.211887043Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2020-09-11T13:44:00.211897743Z Build Operation ID: 7cf16daf-ccef-4ad1-b496-50778dafc913
2020-09-11T13:44:02.114481171Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2020-09-11T13:44:02.490713708Z Running #!/bin/sh
2020-09-11T13:44:02.491320612Z 
2020-09-11T13:44:02.491332412Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2020-09-11T13:44:02.491336512Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2020-09-11T13:44:02.491340212Z 
2020-09-11T13:44:02.491344012Z export NODE_PATH=$(npm root --quiet -g):$NODE_PATH
2020-09-11T13:44:02.491347512Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2020-09-11T13:44:02.493136724Z      export PORT=8080
2020-09-11T13:44:02.493148924Z fi
2020-09-11T13:44:02.493152724Z 
2020-09-11T13:44:02.493341325Z PATH="$PATH:/home/site/wwwroot" npm run start
2020-09-11T13:44:06.600726640Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2020-09-11T13:44:06.600776740Z npm info using npm@6.9.0
2020-09-11T13:44:06.600875440Z npm info using node@v10.14.2
2020-09-11T13:44:06.868226973Z npm info lifecycle core@1.0.0~prestart: core@1.0.0
2020-09-11T13:44:06.885230583Z 
2020-09-11T13:44:06.885248883Z > core@1.0.0 prestart /home/site/wwwroot
2020-09-11T13:44:06.885253583Z > npm run build
2020-09-11T13:44:06.885264583Z 
2020-09-11T13:44:07.662776822Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2020-09-11T13:44:07.663855429Z npm info using npm@6.9.0
2020-09-11T13:44:07.664656534Z npm info using node@v10.14.2
2020-09-11T13:44:07.823510864Z npm info lifecycle core@1.0.0~prebuild: core@1.0.0
2020-09-11T13:44:07.824905373Z npm info lifecycle core@1.0.0~build: core@1.0.0
2020-09-11T13:44:07.835657242Z 
2020-09-11T13:44:07.835673743Z > core@1.0.0 build /home/site/wwwroot
2020-09-11T13:44:07.835678743Z > lb-tsc
2020-09-11T13:44:07.835682343Z
```

At this time I'm stuck with this issue. I saw a reference somewhere on SO that logging in Linux is not completely supported in the log stream (in Azure portal), but I don't know where to find any other logs.
Any help on how I should move forward is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turn out, I had a typo in my settings: `WEBSITE_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT` (Forgot the “S” after WEBSITE).

After chaning this, I didn’t had any problem on deploying. I also noged that the `lb-tsc` command takes around 5-6 minutes when running. This is what probably went wrong when deploying.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your App Service through **Console** or ***Kudu*** in **Advanced Tools**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think you have used a Windows app service when taking the screenshot since the options “clone app” and “app service editor” are not available on linux. Also, for Linux console is called “SSH”